# How to write a report script in Oracle

Tags: oracle, loops

My knowledge on SQL and Oracle does not go beyond querying I'm afraid, but what I'm looking to do is run some kind of script which will produce multiple reports from one execution. I have a whole bunch of code and at the moment I'm rerunning it about 30 times, each time replacing the following in the WHERE clause with a different "SUBJECT_ID":

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
AND (v.SUBJECT_ID LIKE 'B%')
...
```

I'm thinking I should be able to run some kind of loop script and output all the 30 reports in one go...? I am hoping to get some kind of training on this quite soon, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by

> each time replacing the following in the WHERE clause with a different "SUBJECT_ID"

you mean `v.subject_id like '<some value>'`, where  is different for each loop round the code, I would do the following if I were you:

replace the `v.subject_id like '<some value>'` with `v.subject_id like '&&subj_id.'` (the . is necessary to say that's the end of the parameter name) and create that as it's own script, eg. report.sql.

Then I'd create a new script and do:

```
define subj_id set <some value>;

@@report.sql

define subj_id set <some other value>;

@@report.sql

...
```

Comment: Thanks for this - any step-by-step guides on how to create scripts...? Ideally I'm looking to run each query (x30) and save a .xlsx export to a local directory.

Comment: I've not come across any step-by-step guides; basically a script is just a collection of sql and pl/sql statements, along with any sqlplus commands to affect the output (eg. spool to a file, switch off headers, etc). Writing the guts of them isn't too difficult; getting the exact output you need can be slightly more tricky!

Comment: I'd suggest you give it a go, and if you get stuck, ask a new question with details of what you've done, what issues you've had, etc. Table scripts and sample data would help too. [This](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Plus_FAQ) and [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve001.htm) should help you with the sqlplus commands you can use.